# net.thucydides.core.webdriver.UnsupportedDriverException: Could not instantiate class org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver

Tags: selenium, jenkins, serenity-bdd

I am using mac mojave 10.14.3, JDK 1.8, Serenity core 2.0.40 (latest) to develop my test cases. They all run perfectly well either with Chrome ver. 73(100% of time) or Firefox ver. 65.0(99% of time) on my local mac system.
Our Jenkins is running on Redhat linux with no GUI. We installed Firefox browser( **Firefox version 60.5.0** probably the latest available) since Chrome is not supported/ unavailable for RH Linux. When I merged code and ask my admin to run the git branch on Jenkins, I always get errors.

> I have these in my project code itself: 
>   Selenium-java :3.141.59
>
> Selenium-api: 3.141.59
>
> Selenium-server: 3.141.59
>
> geckodriver:0.24.0
>
> chromedriver:2.45.615355

Today after every test running 100% pass on my local Mac system, ran on Jenkins(RH Linux box) I am getting this error (ran 2 times).

```
 net.thucydides.core.webdriver.UnsupportedDriverException: Could not
 instantiate class org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver    at
 net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade.newDriverInstance(WebDriverFacade.java:154)
 Caused by: net.thucydides.core.webdriver.UnsupportedDriverException:
 Could not instantiate new WebDriver instance of type class
 org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver (Timed out waiting 45
seconds for Firefox to start. Build info: version: '3.141.59',
 revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'

 Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting
45 seconds for Firefox to start. Build info: version: '3.141.59',
 revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03' System info: host:
 'xxx', ip: 'xxx', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
 '3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_202' Driver info:
 driver.version: FirefoxDriver

 Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting
 45 seconds for Firefox to start. Build info: version: '3.141.59',
 revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03' System info: host:
 'xxx', ip: 'xxx', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
 '3.10.0-957.5.1.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_202' Driver info:
 driver.version: FirefoxDriver  at
 org.openqa.selenium.firefox.XpiDriverService.waitUntilAvailable(XpiDriverService.java:247)
```

Comment: Consider updating the firefox on the linux jenkins box and make sure to use to use latest gecko driver in your jenkins box.

Comment: If your are running Firefox on RH server without X server,  did you start Firefox in headless mode? You can read about it here: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2017/12/using-headless-mode-in-firefox/

Comment: Since I am using Serenity which is a wrapper around Selenium, Cucumber, they have their own configuration of each browser. For eg.,

For Chrome:
webdriver.driver=chrome
headless.mode = true

For FF: 
webdriver.driver=firefox
gecko.firefox.options = {"args": ["-headless"]}

to be mentiioned in the serenity.properties, which I did. This is working perfectly in my local mac system.

Comment: As it was mentioned, the FF browser on RH can't be upgraded because that is the latest Redhat provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### *********POSSIBLY A BUG ?????**

```
 According to this page, [Serenity BDD Book]https://serenity-bdd.github.io/theserenitybook/latest/web-testing-in-serenity.html
```

I prepared my config.properties file as ...

### Chrome Browser Headless Testing

```
    webdriver.driver=chrome
    headless.mode = true
    drivers.windows.webdriver.chrome.driver = 
       src/test/resources/webdriver/windows/chromedriver.exe
    drivers.mac.webdriver.chrome.driver = 
       src/test/resources/webdriver/mac/chromedriver
    drivers.linux.webdriver.chrome.driver = 
        src/test/resources/webdriver/linux/chromedriver
```

### Firefox Browser Headless Testing

```
      webdriver.driver=firefox
      gecko.firefox.options = {"args": ["-headless"]}
      drivers.mac.webdriver.gecko.driver = 
         src/test/resources/webdriver/mac/geckodriver
      drivers.linux.webdriver.firefox.driver = 
         src/test/resources/webdriver/linux/geckodriver
```

But I was having problem as reported above **UnsupportedDriverException:**
I need to say, everything worked perfectly on my local Mac system, but NOT on RedHat Linux machine with Firefox browser 60.5 version (which should work with geckodriver 0.24.0)

But our Jenkins System Admin added the geckodriver to system path, then it WORKED !!!!!
Our Jenkins Server is running on RedHat Linux.